# jquery - css does not work after .after()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my html code i change the background color of all elements with the id '#mutable', with a click on button 'blue' or 'red'.
With the third button 'load' i .append() a new HTML with the same id.
But the background color does not change for the new elements?
Whats going wrong?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zombinary/tkz1j49u/)

html

```
<div id="mutable" style="width:50px;height:50px;" class="blue">sjdfhksfh</div>
<div id="newHTML">newHTML</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#blue').on('click', function() {
    $('#mutable').trigger('blue');
  });
  $('#red').on('click', function() {
    $('#mutable').trigger('red');
  });

  $('#load').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#newHTML').after('<div id=\"mutable\" style=\"width:50px;height:50px;\">...</div>');
      event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#mutable').bind('red', function(e) {
   $('#mutable').addClass('red').removeClass('blue');
  });
  $('#mutable').bind('blue', function(e) {
    $('#mutable').addClass('blue').removeClass('red');
  });

 });
```

Comment: I couldn't see append method in your js code.

Comment: IDs must be **unique** and you must not duplicate them! That's your problem. The new elements that you append have the same id as the elements before

Comment: sry i meant .after()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always creating a new div with the id `#mutable`. Now jQuery in terms of an ID just runs down the DOM and when it finds the first occurance of your ID, it changes it, but nothing else.

For some solutions, you could use a class `.mutable` instead of an id - but then every created div would be changed on click.

Or you could enumerate your IDs with a number like `#mutable1`, `#mutable2` and so on and change your menu to select the specific div.

Or, to change just the last occurance of your dynamically created divs, use the `:last` - CSS- Pseudoclass.

Answer (score 0):

1) id should be unique at page. And selectors like `#mutable` match only first element with such id -- So after pressing 'load' you create new element with the same id, but $ still match old one

2) try next ( *I just change your id-selector into attr-selector which allow find all elements with id* ):

```
$('#mutable').bind('blue', function(e) {
      //alert('blue');
      $('[id=mutable]:last').addClass('blue').removeClass('red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3wzwr6z/

Comment: Please provide and an alternative using class instead.

Comment: @Alex Char   I'm not sure about what you want as result. Yep, it's better use classes ( possible )

Comment: just follow rule: never duplicate `id` in html